# How do I display the keys of post-meta boolean variables that are true?

Tags: php, boolean, advanced-custom-fields

On a custom post type, I have three boolean-variable advanced custom fields that switch on different locations: First, Second and Third. I want to print those locations on my website. To do this I need to print all of the location keys that are true/1 into an array.

I don't really know where to start, but this is what I have:

```
$2= get_post_meta( $post_id, 'settings_location_second', true );
$3= get_post_meta( $post_id, 'settings_location_third', true );
$location = array($1, $2, $3);

echo join( ', ', $location );
```

Currently, I can only return the location variables in an array, which is a combination of three 0s or 1s.

I want to cut out all the 0s. And then print the keys of all true/1s instead. So it prints, for example: "First, Third"

Comment: What is an example of $1, $2, $3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then you can use array_filter to remove the false, and array_combine to set keys to the array with first, second and third.
Then just grab the keys that is left from the filter.

```
$n1 = true;
$n2 = false;
$n3 = true;

$location = array_combine(['first', 'second', 'third'], array($n1, $n2, $n3));
//$location = ["first" => true, "second" => false, "third" => true]

$location = array_keys(array_filter($location));
//["First", "third"]

echo join( ', ', $location ); // first, third
```

https://3v4l.org/24SNK